# Cutting a chessboard into domino pieces!

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, contest-math

A friend of mine gave me this problem from a  european olympiad:

Suppose we have a $8\times8$ chessboard. Each edge has a number; the number of ways of dividing this chessboard into $1\times2$ and $2\times 1$ domino pieces, such that the edge is part of the division. Find out the last digit of the sum of all these numbers.

Only the outer edges count.

Comment: Could you please reformulate the problem? It's quite hard to parse in its current form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(the question is uncleared, so I assume that the outer edges do not count, otherwise it would be much harder)

There are a total of $7\times 8\times 2=112$ edges. Each way of tiling the dominoes, since there are exactly $32$ dominoes used, each failed to involve $1$ edge, there are a total of $32$ edge not involved in each way of tiling. So each way of tiling contribute to the sum an amount of $112-32=80$. Thus the final digit is $0$.

Comment: The outer edges don't count

Comment: Wow, damn !!, that was sweet.